# Как получить фото всех участников канала с помощью telethon?

Tags: python, telethon

Я хочу взять фото и ники всех участников чата в Telegram. Для этого у меня есть такой код:

```
client = TelegramClient(username, api_id, api_hash)

async def dump_all_participants(channel) -> list:
    offset_user = 0
    limit_user = 100

    all_participants = []
    filter_user = ChannelParticipantsSearch('')

    while True:
        participants = await client(GetParticipantsRequest(channel,
            filter_user, offset_user, limit_user, hash=0))
        if not participants.users:
            break
        all_participants.extend(participants.users)
        offset_user += len(participants.users)

    all_users_details = []

    for participant in all_participants:
        if participant.photo is None:
            photo = UNKNOWN.STRING
        else:
            photo = participant.photo
        all_users_details.append({participant.id: [participant.username, photo]})
    return all_users_details
```

проблема в том, что фотография является объектом Telethon. Я не могу вытащить из него ссылку или просто не знаю, как это сделать

вывод переменной photo: `UserProfilePhoto (photo_id = 208135253786732667, photo_small = FileLocationToBeDeprecated (volume_id = 257125342, local_id = 230348), photo_big = FileLocationToBeDeprecated (volume_id = 257125342, local_id = 257125342, local_id = 257125342, local_id = 257125342)`

Я нашел [InputPhoto в документации по teletone](https://tl.telethon.dev/types/input_photo.html) и надеюсь, что мне это поможет, но документация не содержит примеров использования, и я не могу понять, как это реализовать. Может кто поможет подсказкой или примером как достать оттуда саму фотографию?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно этот метод `get_profile_photos` поможет, подробнее здесь https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html?#telethon.client.chats.ChatMethods.get_profile_photos, код оттуда:

```
# Get the photos of a channel
photos = await client.get_profile_photos(channel)

# Download the oldest photo
await client.download_media(photos[-1])
```

или `iter_profile_photos`, подробнее: https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html?#telethon.client.chats.ChatMethods.iter_profile_photos, код оттуда:

```
# Download all the profile photos of some user
async for photo in client.iter_profile_photos(user):
    await client.download_media(photo)
```

или `download_profile_photo` подробнее: https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html?#telethon.client.downloads.DownloadMethods.download_profile_photo, код оттуда:

```
# Download your own profile photo
path = await client.download_profile_photo('me')
print(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Может еще актуально.

Получать изображения в Telethon можно примерно так:

```
client.download_media(message, file='Тут путь к выходному файлу')
```

Или вот так:

```
message.download_media()
```

Comment: И откуда вообще `message` появился?